# Lisbon Taxi: is it OK to take one Taxi for 2 adults and 3 kids?

Tags: taxis, lisbon

I'm going to visit Lisbon this summer with my family.

We have 3 kids that are age 9, 5 and 3. 
 I think it will be convenient for us to take a taxi during our stay.

However I'm not quite sure if we could call one taxi for our 5. 
We don't mind the little one sit on my lap.
I just wish someone who has the experience to tell me whether this is practical or not.

Comment: I can't speak to Lisbon, but it numerous other cities you can *pre-order* a sufficiently large vehicle for everyone to sit. Use of car seats for children under 12 is compulsory http://www.driving-in.com/portugal/#anchor4. The chances your driver wants to risk fines and loss of license for transporting a lap child—very dangerous in an accident—are small.

Comment: @andrewlazarus. Taxis in cities are exempt from child seats, the only restriction is that children under 12 can't use the front seats. https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cadeirasauto.fundacionmapfre.org/infantis/images/infografia-uso-sillas-pt_tcm727-147116.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjJj8a0-c_LAhXCtxQKHdNyDpYQFggfMAI&usg=AFQjCNHE4oL1IWZg5XhKjEvGiVNvUXih3Q&sig2=J_E5kV_tMDzW2Pby7d8lGg

Comment: "I think it will be convenient for us to take a taxi during our stay." - if you like, you can also ask a separate question about this.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply! Yes, it,s better to book a bigger car. Also I found th metro in Lisbon is also quite convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in many other cities the normal taxi is a car for 5 people (a driver and 4 passengers.)

It's possible that some taxi drivers haven't a problem with transporting an extra passenger, when this is a young child.

In your case I recommend to you order a special taxi ahead of time by phone.

Here are a list of some taxi companies:

- **CNTD - Central Nacional de Táxis Digital**
  +351 21 844 6202
- **Autocoope - Cooperativa De Táxis De Lisboa, Crl.**
  +351 21 793 2756
- **Retális - Rádio Táxis de Lisboa**
  +351 21 811 9000

In my personal experience with taxi drivers in Lisbon (and I'm a Portuguese speaker) it is quite common for the driver to take advantage of the passenger.

Comment: I think the "like in other cities" should be taken out here. For example, in Copenhagen a standard taxi is licensed to carry 4 passengers only, and if you're a larger group than that you need to order a larger car (or more cars) specifically.